# Problem with scrlayer-scrpage's headers

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I somehow miss some headers and it's not due to the page style being wrong. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test with \KOMAScript}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle
\lipsum[5-9]
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 2}
\lipsum[5-7]
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub 3}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Sub 5}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Sub 6}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I simply want alternating subsection and section in the header. And it works most of the time. Somehow if I start a new section (like section 2 in the example) it omits the subsection. Other times, it works just fine (section 3). I have no idea why. The page style is not plain and it really bugs me. When shifting the new section to another page via `\newpage`, it works just fine.

Any ideas are appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example both `\section` and `\subsection` set a bipartite mark: `\section` cleans the right part of the mark and sets the left part to the current section entry. `\subsection` sets the right part to the current subsection and saves the left part unchanged.

There are three kinds of marks: `\botmark` is the last valid mark on a page, `\firstmark` is the first mark set on a page and `\topmark` is the content of `\botmark` from the last page. If there is no new mark on a page `\botmark` and `\firstmark` have the same content as `\topmark`.

Notice that `\leftmark` uses `\botmark` and `\rightmark` uses `\firstmark`.

In your example the first mark on page 3 is set by `\section{Section 2}` so the right part of this first mark on this page is empty. The first mark on page 5 is set by `\subsection{Sub 5}` so the right part of this first mark contains this subsection.

Now you could try something like

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lehead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\rightbotmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test with \KOMAScript}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle
\lipsum[5-9]
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 2}
\lipsum[5-7]
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub 3}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Sub 5}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Sub 6}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

So the right part of the last mark set on a page is in the header of odd pages. But if this last mark is set by a `\section` command you have the same problem again.

You could switch to

```
\rohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\rightbotmark}{\rightmark}}
```

But the header is still empty on odd pages with a `\section` and no `\subsection` command.

Another possibility is using

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test with \KOMAScript}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle
\lipsum[5-9]
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 2}
\lipsum[5-7]
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub 3}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Sub 4}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Sub 5}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Sub 6}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Then the section name will be in the header of odd pages like page 3 in your example where the first mark is set by a `\section` command.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go for a really long if-statement: `\rohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\ifstr{\rightbotmark}{}{\ifstr{\righttopmark}{}{\leftmark}{\righttopmark}}{\rightbotmark}}{\rightmark}}`
In short: I check and use if empty in the following order: `Rightmark` -> `Rightbotmark` -> `Righttopmark` -> `Leftmark`. And it works great in the example given above. However, when I use it with my document, it won't detect `rightmark` as being empty and thus printing no header. Any idea why that is?